# C#.NET Regex on finding a space after a punctuation

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

Here's my current regex: `[^\s][\.,\?!:][\w]`.
I need to check if there's a space after every punctuations such as `[.,!:?]`.
But I have a problem, the type of file that I am checkin is `*.sgm`, so theres a certain tags that is something like this:

```
<at.cit><at.cit>> </at.cit> <case.cit><lit> </lit></case.cit>
```

For example:

```
<ptext>Text.Text<at.cit>Text</at.cit></ptext>
```

So I need to match only `"t.T"` because we need a space after the period. But my regex will find `"t.T"` and `"t.c"` and `"t.c"`. How can I eliminate those tags?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This looks very similar to (X)HTML, which means regex is not a good solution.

Comment: Are you parsing XML or HTML? If so, there's already parsers for that. Also, don't use regex for HTML.

Comment: you're going to make people mad - asking how to parse HTML, XHTML, or XML with regex

Comment: I need to check *.SGM, so I need to use regex, because we are using certainstandards here at work, the apps that I am creating will be use by Editors, so I need to use regex for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for regex `(?<![<\/])\b\w*(\w[.,?!:]\w)\w*\b(?!\>)`.

Comment: this looks great and close to the right answer, but I try to make a tag for example : <ptext style="test.gif">etc.,  and the regex match test.gif. But thanks for the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Omega thanks for your help! I fix now the issue beacuse of your answer. Thanks a lot! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other commentators that you should use a library that's made for parsing the format in C#.  If you absolutely have to hack it with a regex for some reason you could use the following:

```
>(?<Text>([\w]*(?<Hit>\.\S))+[\w]*)<
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\S[.,?!:]\w(?!(?<=<[^<>]*)(?=[^<>]*>))
```

If the current position it inside a tag, the lookbehind - `(?<=<[^<>]*)` - and lookahead - `(?=[^<>]*>)` - will both be true.  Wrapping them in a negative lookahead prevents a match inside a tag.